# What is the reason for Activity Window size shrink in Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-emulator, material-design

**In Emulator:(Same in All size Emulators)**

[image]

**In My Android Device:**

[image]

What is the reason for this and How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your code?